# Ruby/chef: IF ELSE statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, chef-infra

Trying to set template variable {USE_EXISTING_SCHEMA} to = true or false based on whether or not {CREATE_OID_SCHEMA} is = to true.
should I be using == or = when specifying the IF condition of {CREATE_OID_SCHEMA}?

```
case node['fmw']['shortname']
      when /oid1/
        IS_SECOND_OID_INSTALL = "false"
        CONFIGURE_OVD_COMPONENT = "true"
        CREATE_OID_SCHEMA = "true"
          if CREATE_OID_SCHEMA = "true" then
            USE_EXISTING_SCHEMA = "false"
          else USE_EXISTING_SCHEMA = "true"
      when /oid2/
        IS_SECOND_OID_INSTALL = "true"
        CONFIGURE_OVD_COMPONENT = "false"
        CREATE_OID_SCHEMA = "false"
          if CREATE_OID_SCHEMA = "true" then
            USE_EXISTING_SCHEMA = "false"
          else USE_EXISTING_SCHEMA = "true"
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` operator is always an assignment operator, even in an if statement. Thus, your statement

```
if CREATE_OID_SCHEMA = "true" then
```

always assigns the string `"true"` to the `CREATE_OID_SCHEMA` constant (and outputs a warning at that). Since the string `"true"` is also truethy, the if statement will always match.

Going forward, you probably want to update your code as follows:

```
case node['fmw']['shortname']
when /oid1/
  is_second_oid_install = "false"
  configure_ovd_component = "true"
  create_oid_schema = "true"

  if create_oid_schema == "true"
    use_existing_schema = "false"
  else
    use_existing_schema = "true"
  end
when /oid2/
  is_second_oid_install = "true"
  configure_ovd_component = "false"
  create_oid_schema = "false"

  if create_oid_schema == "true"
    use_existing_schema = "false"
  else
    use_existing_schema = "true"
  end
end
```

In the code above, I have performed the following changes:

- In the if statement, I use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.
- variables in Ruby should always start with a lower-case letter and use `snake_case`. Bare words starting with an upper-case letter are considered constants in Ruby which should only be assigned once.
- The `then` keyword should usually not be used. Use newlines instead.

When further updating your code, you should use real boolean values (`true` and `false`) instead of strings containing the word. That way, you can shorten your comparisons and better reflect your intentions. Generally, all values but `false` and `nil` are truethy in Ruby (and thus match in an if statement). This includes all strings, numbers, regular expressions, ...

Comment: The `if` statement can be extracted from the `case`. Then you only need one.